# fluid object not baking

Tags: fluid-simulation

I haven't found this question answered yet and I'm stuck. I'm trying to bake a simple fluid sim. I have the domain enclosing the entire scene. My fluid object is inside a glass-shaped obstacle (closed, solidified). I want it to spill uot from the glass onto the floor, but the fluid object does not turn to fluid when baked. I have deleted every new cache so that there are never more than one in the directory and yet still the fluid object doesn't change. what am I missing?

image: domain and fluid object are highlighted, baking specs in the physics panel. The scene also includes a ground plane, two wall planes each with a displacement modifier, and two emission planes. The glass has been set as a fluid obstacle as have the ground plane and wall planes. 
[image]

Comment: Can you add a .blend file? Possibly using http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 1):

I closed the file and reopened, deleting all previous caches and now it seems to work. :-b